# were Irrational numbers discovered at Archimedes's age?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, math-history, real-numbers

[Archimedes axiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Properties_of_Real_Numbers#Theorem_.28Archimedes_axiom.29) states a property of real numbers, while the real numbers include all the rational numbers and all the irrational numbers.

I wonder were Irrational numbers discovered at Archimedes's age?

I think the question is equivalent to ask : Does [Hippasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus)( he is sometimes credited with the discovery of the existence of irrational numbers)
live earlier than Archimedes?

> Hippasus of Metapontum (/ˈhɪpəsəs/; Greek: Ἵππασος, Híppasos; fl. 5th
>   century BC)
>
> Archimedes of Syracuse (/ˌɑːkɪˈmiːdiːz/;[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus) Greek: Ἀρχιμήδης; c. 287
>   BC – c. 212 BC)

P.S. I am Chinese , I don't understand these *BCs*

Comment: Wikipedia explains the meaning of BC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini

Comment: Yes: Hippasos lived approximately 200 years before Archimedes.

Comment: I recommend History of Science and Mathematics SE

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There actually is no "year 0", because the years are enumerated positionally. Jesus Christ was supposedly born in the year 1 or, more verbosely, "in the *first* year of the christian era". So the enumeration goes like: 3BC, 2BC, 1BC, 1AD, 2AD et cetera.

Comment: Hippasus : 5th century BC. Archimedes : ca.287-ca.212 BC i.e. 3rd century BC. [BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era) stay for Before Christ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP wrote: "Archimedes axiom states a property of real numbers, while the real numbers include all the rational numbers and all the irrational numbers." It should be clear that the property in question is referred to as the *Archimedes axiom* only since about 1880 when the term was introduced by [Otto Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Stolz).

The OP further asks: "I wonder were Irrational numbers discovered at Archimedes's age?"

The answer is most likely negative.  The Greeks thought mostly in terms of proportions among whole numbers.  The idea of systematizing the number system to include roots and other irrationals is mainly due to [Simon Stevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin) who lived almost two thousand years later.